# In Joomla how i can put an image on the principal page and when i click the image this open an article?

Tags: image, url, joomla, article

I'm using joomla 3.0.3.

I want to put a simple image on the principal page and when I click this image, automatically (changes the page) and opens an article with some info that I want to put on it.

It is possible?

With joomla default, or I need an extension for can do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand. How is this not simply a link to a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a menu item for the **blog** view of frontpage or content.

This will load a number of articles and paginate them.  In the options, you will find Intro articles (on top), then the number of articles to load in columns, then a list of links.  Put 0 on the links and on the first articles, and you will get your list of articles in a grid.

Depending on the template you are using, the settings of the menu link could be enough to achieve what you want; if not you can write a template override to display exactly what you want.